# Can't get PHPMailer working locally

Tags: php, email, smtp, localhost, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer, which works fine on my server, but not on my localhost. The function I'm using to send is:

```
function sendEmail($mail, $toEmail, $toName, $subject, $message, $noHtmlMessage) {
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'christopherpickardco.netfirms.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'webmaster@christopherpickard.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'myPassword';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('webmaster@christopherpickard.com', 'ChrisComposes.com'); //
$mail->addAddress($toEmail, $toName);     // Add a recipient. Right now this goes to me, in the end it will go to Chris
$mail->addReplyTo('webmaster@christopherpickard.com', 'ChrisComposes.com');

$mail->Subject = "ChrisComposes.com: " . $subject;
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $noHtmlMessage;

$mail->send(); 
}
```

This works fine on my server but on my localhost I get an error: Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`smtp.eigbox.net' did not match expected CN=`christopherpickardco.netfirms.com' in /Users/ChristopherPickard/Web_Development/chriscomposes/includes/phpmailer/class.smtp.php on line 344

How can I fix this?

Comment: Isn't is obvious that it can work only on the site specified? So when you run it on localhost, the eightbox.net receives host name as localhost instead of christopherpicardco.netfirms.com. so due to security issues it wouldn't work.

Comment: If it were obvious to me I wouldn't have asked, but thank you. Plenty of people seem to have it working in localhosts, so there must be a way

Comment: Which server software are you using as localhost?

Comment: It is obvious because this exact error is covered in the docs, so go read them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From docs:

> The correct fix for this is to replace the invalid, misconfigured or
>   self-signed certificate with a good one. Failing that, you can allow
>   insecure connections via the SMTPOptions property introduced in
>   PHPMailer 5.2.10 (it's possible to do this by subclassing the SMTP
>   class in earlier versions), though this is not recommended:
>
> ```
> $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
>     'ssl' => array(
>         'verify_peer' => false,
>         'verify_peer_name' => false,
>         'allow_self_signed' => true
>     )
> );
> ```

This works.